# AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I'm following documentation [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) about Inline formsets and have an error: 'UserProfile' has not attribute 'objects'.

Why?

Is there any alternative for getting this object from UserProfile?

Please notice that I'm new to Django, so every explanation is welcome.

My **shell code**:

```
UserProfileFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile, fields=('city',))
city = UserProfile.objects.get(city='Salzburg')
formset = UserProfileFormSet(instance=city)
```

UserProfile from **models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
website = models.URLField(default='')
phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: are all your migrations up to date?

Comment: feels like `UserProfile` got override. Is there any other class names this ?

Comment: @itzmeontv I searched all project, but UserProfile class is clearly defined only in one place.

Comment: @RichSmith Yes, 'No changes detected'

Comment: check `type(UserProfile)` in shell

Comment: @itzmeontv <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>

Comment: how you imported `UserProfile` ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't figure out. Add `objects = models.Manager()` to your `UserProfile` class.Reload shell and try.

Comment: @Bijoy Yes. Otherwise it should return: "'UserProfile' is not defined" I think.

Comment: can you do `from models import UserProfile as userprofile` and see if userprofile is having the attribute objects

Comment: @itzmeontv Now there is: 'accounts.models.DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.'

Comment: That error gives you enough details to continue.